.NET Framework 4.7.2 equivalent of dotnet test | Altcover with 4.7.2
What is the dotnet test equivalent of .NET Framework 4.7.2?
I am trying to integrate altcover in my project. The instructions on the wiki all have commands using the dotnet command. But since my project uses 4.7.2, I do not have the dotnet command.
It also says online that altcover works with .NET framework as well. But I can't figure out how to use it.
I have installed altcover using nuget, but do not know how to proceed further. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

altcover is not a testing framework, but a coverage collector. What exactly are you trying to do?

Yes, I am trying to collect code coverage. My tests are written using Xunit. The commands on the wiki involve using dotnet test a lot. Hence was asking for the equivalent command in 4.7.2. Maybe using MSBuild?

I don't remember how this was done back then :-( But there shouldn't be any difference to what you have used so far. How did you so far run your tests?

Which testing framework are you using in tests?

I am using Xunit for my tests.

How do you currently run your tests?

I also had to dig through a lot of documentation to get it working for a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project using NUnit in the following way (source - plus a few other docs I had to go through)
I'll simplify the steps a bit, but feel free to go through the source for a better understanding -

You'll need altcover.exe - you can get it with the dotnet CLI (dotnet tool install --global altcover.global) - if your NuGet package gave you the same altcover.exe you can skip this
You'll need a test runner, in my case it was nunit3-console.exe, in your case it would be XUnit Runner Console
Clean & build your test project using MSBuild to generate your Test assemblies
We first need to instrument the binaries - inside <test-folder>/bin/Debug, run the following : AltCover.exe --outputDirectory=__Instrumented .More details on the CLI flags can be found in the Usage docs if you want to filter assemblies etc.
Use AltCover with your XUnit runner : AltCover.exe Runner --recorderDirectory __Instrumented  --executable <full-path-to-xunit-console.exe> --  ./__Instrumented/<test-assembly>.dll (same docs above for more flags)
(Optional) with the generated coverage.xml, you can use ReportGenerator to generate a html output

I've written a post for a more detailed explanation of the steps.
